# Definition of Markov chain: question about stationarity

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

My notes define a Markov chain in the following way:

A Markov chain is a stochastic process $\{X_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ with a state space $\mathcal{S}$ that is at most countable and that satisfies the Markov-property:

For every $n \geq1$ and $(x_0, \dots, x_{n+1})\in \mathcal{S}^{n+2}$ with $\mathbb{P}(X_0 = x_0, \dots, X_n = x_n) > 0$ we have

$$\mathbb{P}(X_{n+1} = x_{n+1}\mid X_n = x_n, \dots, X_0 = x_0) = \mathbb{P}(X_{n+1} = x_{n+1}\mid X_n = x_n)$$

Moreover, the probabilities $\mathbb{P}(X_{n+1} = y \mid X_n = x)$ are stationary for all $x, y \in \mathcal{S}$ with $\mathbb{P}(X_n = x) > 0$: they do not depend on $n$ (= for all $n \geq 0$ the probabilities give the same result).

**Question**:

My question concerns the stationary part of the definition. Does this definition imply the following equivalence? (to make all conditional probabilities exist)

$$\exists n \geq 0: \mathbb{P}(X_n = x) > 0 \iff \forall n \geq 0: \mathbb{P}(X_n = x) >0$$

Comment: Does your question miss a ">0" in the end? If so, what if you consider a chain with two states (0 and 1) and where at each time the chain moves from 1 to 0 (or from 0 to 1) with probability one.

Comment: @user52227 I fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My PhD is in discrete Markov chains, and I've *never* heard this use of terminology. What you have is a time homogeneous Markov chain.
What this means is the following.

> When you look at $P_n = \{ P(X_{n+1} = y \mid X_n = x) \mid x,y \in S\}$, you are looking at all the possibilities for the transition from the Markov chain's $n$-th position to its $(n+1)$-st.
> So first you need to look at $P_0$, then $P_1$, etc.
>
> If $P_n$ is independent of $n$, then this means that each jump has the same distribution. Overwhelmingly such time homogeneous Markov chains are studied---although perhaps we, as a community, are wrong to not study inhomogeneous ones more...

---

The standard use of the term "stationarity" is very different. A *distribution* $\pi$ (on $S$) is called a stationary measure (my preferred term is "invariant distribution"; it's also known as an "equilibrium distribution") if the distribution of $X_n$ is $\pi$ when $X_0 \sim \pi$.
So if a time-homogeneous chain has matrix $P$, then $\pi P = \pi$.
It's called "equilibrium" distribution, since under certain (fairly weak) conditions one can show that, *regardless of $X_0$*, we have $P(X_n = j \mid X_0 = i) \to \pi(j)$ as $n \to \infty$.

---

Note that "$\exists n : P(X_n = x) > 0$" certain doesn't not imply that $P(X_n = x) > 0$ for all $n$. For example, take the simple Markov chain that has two vertices in the state space and always moves to vertex 1:
$$ P = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}. $$
If you start at the second vertex, or let $X_0$ be some measure that is not a point mass at $1$, then the claim is violated: $P(X_0 = 2) > 0$ but $P(X_n = 1) = 1$ for all $n \ge 1$.

---

An excellent book on Markov chains is by James Norris. It really is the go-to reference, in my opinion. Grimmett also has some good stuff. (Just search for their names and "Markov chains" on your favoured search engine, aka Google.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The wikipedia page does mention "stationary markov chains", which is what I meant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Discrete-time_Markov_chain.

Comment: Also, I'm sorry to inform you that this doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: I don't understand your question then. Maybe there's a typo in the final line?

Comment: Do you understand (or agree with) my definition of markov chain? If so, the question I'm asking is that if a transition probability $P(X_{n+1}=y\mid X_n = x)$ exists (i.e. $P(X_n =x)>0$), then the stationarity implies it exists for all $n$, thus does it follow that $P(X_n =x)>0$ for all $n$ in that case? ( and conversely). Sorry that the question isn't clear.

Comment: You say that $P(X_n = x)>0$ for some n does not imply that it holds for all $n$. But in this case $P(X_{n+1} = y\mid X_n = x)$ exists and by stationarity it exists for all $n$ and is equal to this probability. In particular, $P(X_n = x)>0$ for all n in order to make the conditional probability defined. Where do I go wrong?

Comment: Maybe, the stationary part in the definition only applies when the conditional probabilities are defined? I.e. $P(X_{n+1} = y\mid X_n = x) = P(X_{m+1} = y \mid X_m = x)$ for all $n,m$ with $P(X_n = x) > 0, P(X_m = x) > 0$?.

Comment: Sorry about being slow to reply -- I've been very busy! I don't know what you mean by "by stationarity". If you check your definition in your OP, you say "for [past event] which non-zero probability". $P(X_{n+1} = y \mid X_n = x)$ is undefined if $X_n = x$ is a null-event (ie has probability 0)

Comment: I reread your answer and it was very clear to me now. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! =D